# XSD: how to use restriction on a group of key-value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

My actual xml are something like this:

```
<gender code="2" display="female />
```

The code for gender is 1-male, 2-female. Now I've already got xsd like this:

```
<xs:element name="gender">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:int">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="int">
                    <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="displayName" type="xs:string">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction>
                    <xs:enumeration value="male"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="female"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But it is also valid for this xml:

```
<gender code="2" display="male />
```

I'm looking for xs:restriction but it seems not helpful.Is there another way to fix my xsd?

Comment: I can't recognize, why you bother with these redundant (non-normalized) elements at all. `code` already contains the essential information, and `display` seems just  beautification for human consumption; I can't see a reson to include it in the scheme and even less so to every person element separately.

Answer (score 0):

To impose constraints across multiple attributes, you need XSD 1.1 assertions:

```
<xs:assert test="(@code=1 and @display='male') 
                or (@code=2 and @display='female')"/>
```

as a child of the `xs:element`.

But not all schema processors support XSD 1.1.